# AllocConsole() - ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED on alternate run

Tags: c#, kernel32

I'm currently using .NET `dll` which calls `AllocConsole()` in the static constructor of a class.
I noticed that `AllocConsole()` returns 0 during alternate runs, 
and `GetLastError()` would return `0x5 - ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED.`

Any idea what could be wrong?

***Note: I did not see any console popping out even when `AllocConsole()` returns non-zero.**

2015/01/08
I did a `FreeConsole()`, `AllocConsole()` if the first `AllocConsole()` returns 0, and it no longer gives `Error 0x5`. But I still don't see any console being displayed.

Comment: Are you running this in the VS debugger?

Comment: The 99% accurate guess is that AllocConsole() fails because the process already has a console.  Yes, produces error 5.  It is a function that does **not** belong in a DLL, only the main EXE can do this reliably and accurately.

Comment: @Chris I'm running it on program that takes in a custom dll, which in turn consumes the dll that calls AllocConsole().

Comment: @HansPassant So it is a bad idea to call AllocConsole() in a class library?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: If this is running under .NET why not just use the built-in `Console` class instead? It provides all the access to most console functions, and manages the API calls under the hood.

Comment: @Alejandro The program calling the dll is not a console app. I don't think directly calling the `Console` class works?